# C# class does not implement inherited abstract member

Tags: c#

I am sorry if I am asking something stupid but I am completely a newbie in C# and ASP.NET.
I am having an error in my code and I don't understand it.
I am working on Visual Studio 2008.

In this line of code:

```
public class SQLFAQProvider : DBFAQProvider
```

I am getting this error:

> `Moby.Commerce.DataAccess.FAQ.SQLFAQProvider` does not implement inherited abstract member `Moby.Commerce.DataAccess.FAQDBFAQProvider.DeleteFAQbyID(int)`

When I go to `DBFAQProvider` the error is in this line of code:

```
public abstract DBFAQ DeleteFAQbyID(int fAQID);
```

What should I change to correct it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First thought would be implement the abstract member in the inherited class ala:

```
public class SQLFAQProvider : DBFAQProvider
{
    public override DBFAQ DeleteFAQbyID(int fAQID)
    {
        //TODO: Real Code
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that it requires the override keyword when an abstract member must be implemented.

Comment: IMO the `override` keyword is rightly required in the concrete class as the abstract member can be further overridden in a class derived from the concrete one. Otherwise it would look like a member of the derived class overrides a non-virtual or non-abstract member. Furthermore the CLR must be able to make a distinction between an implementation of the abstract member and a potential new member that hides the abstract one. The real question then is why isn't this allowed i.e. to simultaneously override and hide a member (be it an abstract or a virtual one) since there will be no ambiguity.

Answer (score 23):

Implement the `DeleteFAQbyID` method in your derived class:

```
public override DBFAQ DeleteFAQbyID(int fAQID)
{
    // Put your code here
}
```

The point of an abstract method is to say (in the abstract base class), "I want to make sure that this method is available in every concrete class deriving from me" - it's up to you to provide the implementation. It's a bit like a method in an interface.

Comment: I would rephrase "I want to make sure that this method is available in every concrete class deriving from me" to "I want to make sure that every concrete class deriving from me implements custom specific logic for this method"

Answer (score 11):

Your subclass needs to explicitly implement that particular method.

If you have no idea how to do it, then at least do:

```
public override DBFAQ DeleteFAQbyID(int fAQID)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException("This isn't done yet");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

When you inherit from a class in C#, you are required to implement all methods marked as `abstract` unless your class is itself marked as `abstract`. Abstract classes are ones that cannot be directly instantiated at runtime because they don't fully implement all of the required methods that the base class(es) say must exist.

Abstract methods are a mechanism that allows a class to indicate that a particular method must "eventually" exist - without having to provide an implementation at that point. You typically use abstract classes when you cannot or don't want to dictate what a particular implementation should do, but you need to pre-define a method that you will eventually rely on.

To fix your problem either mark your class as abstract (with the expectation that another level of inheritance will fill in the missing pieces) or implement DeleteFAQbyId() in your class:

```
public DBFAQ DeleteFAQbyID(int fAQID)
{
    // write appropriate implementation here or:
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    // or possibly NotSupportedException() if the operation should can't ever be supported.
}
```

Comment: Note that in order to implement a method one must declare it as "override", otherwise the error will persist

Answer (score 3):

When a class inherits from an abstract class it must implement all abstract methods defined by said class.  This is the class interface, the abstract methods can be thought of as pure virtual functions, i.e., functions that must be implemented by descended classes but do not make sense to be implemented in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `SQLFAQProvider` class isn't `abstract`, it has to implement every `abstract` method that it inherits.

To fix this, implement the `DeleteFAQbyID` method in `SQLFAQProvider`, like this:

```
public override DBFAQ DeleteFAQbyID(int fAQID) {
    //Do something
}
```

Alternatively, you could make your `SQLFAQProvider` class `abstract` by changing its declaration to `public abstract class SQLFAQProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Your subclass (SQLFAQProvider) must provide implementation code for the method DeleteFAQbyID because the parent class (DBFAQProvider) did not.

Answer (score -2):

In the abstract class use an entity property like `IsValid`. Make it return the abstract method that you want to override in the derived class.

In abstract base class:

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        return  DeleteFAQbyID();
    }
}

public abstract bool DeleteFAQbyID();
```

In the derived class now it will override the abstract class' method.